NPM not being able to find a file, this issue occurred while trying to install "ews-javascript-api-auth" package on the server
I tried to install "ews-javascript-api-auth" npm package and works fine on my machine but when I pushed it to the server I found this issue NPM not being able to find a file.
npm notice New minor version of npm available! 10.2.4 -> 10.5.2
npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.5.2>
npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@10.5.2` to update!
npm notice 
npm verb stack Error: An unknown git error occurred
npm verb stack     at makeError (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/git/lib/make-error.js:28:13)
npm verb stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/git/lib/spawn.js:37:26
npm verb stack     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
npm verb cwd /app
npm verb Linux 5.14.0-284.43.1.el9_2.x86_64
npm verb node v18.19.1
npm verb npm  v10.2.4
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent An unknown git error occurred
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 
npm verb exit -2
npm verb unfinished npm timer reify 1713337840513
npm verb unfinished npm timer reify:unpack 1713337841255
npm verb unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/ntlm-client 1713337841265
npm verb code -2

